# How to put the column wise elements inside a box followed by a label in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

How to place the column wise elements inside a box with a short label below.

I have tried, but not getting the desired output. The current compiled output is shown below.

I want to place a box covering whole D1 and plk(D2) nodes, similarly also for the other two nodes, i.e. k1(D1) and D2 (column wise). Also want to put a label just below that box. Please help me.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, quotes, arrows.meta, arrows, calc, shadows, positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 22mm and 22mm,
mybox/.style = {draw, ultra thick, text width=22mm, minimum height=11mm, align=center,
    inner sep=2mm, outer sep=0mm},
every edge/.style = {draw, thick, shorten >=2mm, shorten <=2mm,
    bend left, -Stealth},
every edge quotes/.append style={sloped, font=\sffamily\scriptsize, auto},
]
\begin{scope}

\node[] (sa)    {D\textsubscript{1}};
\node[] (sb)  [right=of sa] {kl(D\textsubscript{1})};
\node[] (sc)  [below=of sa] {plk(D\textsubscript{2})};
\node[] (sd)  [right=of sc] {D\textsubscript{2}};

\end{scope}

\draw
(sa)  edge ["ald"] (sb) 
(sb)  edge  ["ald\textsuperscript{-1}"] (sa)
(sc)  edge ["sld"]  (sd)
(sd)  edge ["sld\textsuperscript{-1}"] (sc)
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Try.}
\label{f1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this come close?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, quotes, arrows.meta, arrows, calc, shadows, positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 22mm and 22mm,
mybox/.style = {draw, ultra thick, text width=22mm, minimum height=11mm, align=center,
    inner sep=2mm, outer sep=0mm},
every edge/.style = {draw, thick, shorten >=2mm, shorten <=2mm,
    bend left, -Stealth},
every edge quotes/.append style={sloped, font=\sffamily\scriptsize, auto},
small box/.style={draw,minimum width=2em,minimum height=1em}
]
\begin{scope}

\node[] (sa)    {D\textsubscript{1}};
\node[] (sb)  [right=of sa] {kl(D\textsubscript{1})};
\node[] (sc)  [below=of sa] {plk(D\textsubscript{2})};
\node[] (sd)  [right=of sc] {D\textsubscript{2}};
\node[small box,label=below:x] at ($(sa)!0.5!(sb)$){};
\node[small box,label=below:y] at ($(sc)!0.5!(sd)$){};
\end{scope}

\draw
(sa)  edge ["ald"] (sb) 
(sb)  edge  ["ald\textsuperscript{-1}"'] (sa)
(sc)  edge ["sld"]  (sd)
(sd)  edge ["sld\textsuperscript{-1}"'] (sc)
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Try.}
\label{f1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

To fit the nodes in a box, use the `fit` library.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending,quotes, positioning,fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 25mm and 22mm,
mybox/.style = {draw, ultra thick, text width=22mm, minimum height=11mm, align=center,
    inner sep=2mm, outer sep=0mm},
every edge/.style = {draw, thick, shorten >=2mm, shorten <=2mm,
    bend left=60, -{Stealth[bend]}},
every edge quotes/.append style={sloped, font=\sffamily\scriptsize, auto},
]
\begin{scope}

\node[] (sa)    {D\textsubscript{1}};
\node[] (sb)  [right=of sa] {kl(D\textsubscript{1})};
\node[] (sc)  [below=of sa] {plk(D\textsubscript{2})};
\node[] (sd)  [right=of sc] {D\textsubscript{2}};
\node[fit=(sa)(sb),draw,inner ysep=0pt,label=below:x]{};
\node[fit=(sc)(sd),draw,inner ysep=0pt,label=below:y]{};
\end{scope}

\draw
(sa)  edge ["ald"] (sb) 
(sb)  edge  ["ald\textsuperscript{-1}"'] (sa)
(sc)  edge ["sld"]  (sd)
(sd)  edge ["sld\textsuperscript{-1}"'] (sc)
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Try.}
\label{f1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok thanks. Let me try.!

Comment: Label is okay. But box is not as desired. I want to cover both D1 and plk(D2) inside that box. Is it possible? Here I suppose we need to set the width as 3cm perhaps?

Comment: @MishraS You can use `fit` for that.

Comment: But will this be applicable for the nodes sa and sc and sb and sd

Comment: @MishraS I added an example. I think there is some language barrier, I do not understand what you mean. You can fit an arbitrary number of nodes in general, but may need `rotate fit` to improve the result (seems not necessary here).

Comment: The question says “I want to place a box between D1 and plk(D2) nodes, similarly also for the other two nodes, i.e. k1(D1) and D2“. I'm lost!

Comment: See my edit. Mistakenly, i posted row instead column. I am sorry. Please see my last edit. Now it works. Thanks. The `fit` thing works.

Answer (score 1):

The [updated question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/531476/revisions) says:

> I want to place a box covering whole D1 and plk(D2) nodes, similarly also for the other two nodes, i.e. k1(D1) and D2 (column wise).

What follows answers *that question* using the Ti*k*Z `fit` library:

```latex
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit, shapes, quotes, arrows.meta, arrows, calc, shadows,
                positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance = 40mm and 22mm,
  mybox/.style = {draw, ultra thick, text width=22mm, minimum height=11mm,
                  align=center,
      inner sep=2mm, outer sep=0mm},
  every edge/.style = {draw, thick, shorten >=2mm, shorten <=2mm,
                       bend left, -Stealth},
  every edge quotes/.append style={sloped, font=\sffamily\scriptsize, auto},
  ]

\begin{scope}
  \node (sa)               {D\textsubscript{1}};
  \node (sb) [right=of sa] {kl(D\textsubscript{1})};
  \node (sc) [below=of sa] {plk(D\textsubscript{2})};
  \node (sd) [right=of sc] {D\textsubscript{2}};
\end{scope}

\draw
  (sa.north -| sc.east) edge ["ald"] (sb.north west)
  (sb.south west) edge ["ald\textsuperscript{-1}"] (sa.south -| sc.east)
  (sc.north east) edge ["sld"]  (sd.north -| sb.west)
  (sd.south -| sb.west) edge ["sld\textsuperscript{-1}"] (sc.south east);

\path node (m) [draw, inner sep=0, outer sep=0, fit=(sa) (sc)] {}
      node[font=\tiny, inner ysep = 0, below=1mm of m] {below A};

\path node (n) [draw, inner sep=0, outer sep=0, fit=(sb) (sd)] {}
      node[font=\tiny, inner ysep = 0, below=1mm of n] {below B};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please see the update.

Comment: Okay thanks. I came to know about fit. many thanks.

Comment: The problem is that you asked something, but apparently wanted something entirely different. This is beyond my understanding.

Comment: My bad. Hurriedly, I have asked something different instead of some other thing. Sorry for this.

Comment: The question *as it is written [now](https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/531476/revisions)* still does *not* correspond to the accepted answer. Anyway, this is pointless, I'm out.

Comment: Who downvoted, and why??